# MSSQLServer 2008 in virtual pc

Tags: sql-server, virtual-pc

What are your experiences with running SQL server in a virtual pc?
Currently we have an sql2008 instance running in a virtual machine.
Both CPU's hit the roof the moment a query is executed.

what are your experiences and what do you suggest in this matter?

Answer (score 2):

I've had some serious performance issues using virtualised SQL servers for database heavy applications (ETL development).  See [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149318/virtualized-sql-server-why-not#149381) for a run-down on my experiences and the outcomes of digging into the underlying issues.

Essentially a DB heavy process like ETL will thrash the I/O (more sequential operations, so it isn't waiting for disk seeks as much as an OLTP app) and Translation Lookaside Buffer (large data sets), both of which are very slow on a naively virtualised image.  The posting links out to [this whitepaper on AMD's site](http://developer.amd.com/assets/NPT-WP-1%201-final-TM.pdf) (written by a vendor so take with a grain of salt) which (in between extolling the virtues of AMD's new Opteron chips) talks a bit about the underlying issues.

Comment: Thanks, although I don't think I have exactly the same issues, this looks like a lot of starting research points. thanks

Comment: I was gonna post the other stackoverflow question (it's _my_ question!), but you beat me to it: upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using VMWare?  If so apply service packs from back in September and since.

Otherwise you can limit the resources that 2008 uses if you have no limited of a machine.